# "cannot find function" when trying to follow FFI example

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm trying to get started with Rust FFI, so I went to [the nomicon's documentation on FFI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html) and tried replicate the "Foreign calling conventions" example.

I made a simple bit of code that just copy-pastes the example and tries to use the function that's declared:

```
extern crate libc;

#[cfg(all(target_os = "win32", target_arch = "x86"))]
#[link(name = "kernel32")]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
extern "stdcall" {
    fn SetEnvironmentVariableA(n: *const u8, v: *const u8) -> libc::c_int;
}

fn main() {
    println!("Enter main");
    unsafe {
        let ret = SetEnvironmentVariableA("SOME_NEW_ENV_VAR\0", "NEW_ENV_VAR_VAL\0");
        println!("ret: {}", ret);
    }
    println!("Exit main");
}
```

This doesn't really do anything useful, I just wanted to see if I could link to and call a function without everything exploding.

I get this error from the compiler:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `SetEnvironmentVariableA` in this scope
  --> src\main.rs:13:19
   |
13 |         let ret = SetEnvironmentVariableA("SOME_NEW_ENV_VAR\0","NEW_ENV_VAR_VAL\0");
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

Is the example out of date?  Am I missing something obvious? It seems like no matter what, the `SetEnvironmentVariableA` that I declare should be in scope.

I'm aware of the winapi crate, but I'm trying to learn Rust FFI; using an existing crate that solves the problem would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Are you sure you compile on `#[cfg(all(target_os = "win32", target_arch = "x86"))]` ?

Comment: I'm on windows, so win32 and x86 should produce a compatible binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Stargateur was the right direction.  Removing the following line fixed the problem:

```
#[cfg(all(target_os = "win32", target_arch = "x86"))]
```

The [`cfg` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) was used in the "Foreign calling conventions" section of the tutorial, so I figured it was somehow part of the magic to get the linking and calling convention to work. That's not how `cfg` works at all.   The URL of the documentation alone explains why I was getting the "cannot find function" error: "conditional compilation".

I was able to extend the example into a sort of hello world:

```
#[link(name = "kernel32")]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
extern "stdcall" {
    fn SetEnvironmentVariableA(n: *const u8, v: *const u8) -> i32;
    fn GetEnvironmentVariableA(n: *const u8, v: *mut u8, s : u32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    println!("Enter main");
    unsafe {
        let ret = SetEnvironmentVariableA("HELLO_WORLD_VAR\0".as_ptr(),"hellow world!\0".as_ptr());
        println!("ret: {}", ret);
        let mut dummy : u8 = 0;
        let ret1 = GetEnvironmentVariableA("HELLO_WORLD_VAR\0".as_ptr(), &mut dummy, 0);
        println!("ret1: {}", ret1);
        if ret1 > 0 {
            let mut read = vec![0; ret1 as usize];
            let ret2 = GetEnvironmentVariableA("HELLO_WORLD_VAR\0".as_ptr(),read.as_mut_ptr(), ret1 as u32);
            let read_str = String::from_utf8(read).unwrap();
            println!("ret2: {}", ret2);
            println!("read_str: {}", read_str);
            println!("read_str.len(): {}", read_str.len());
        }
    }
    println!("Exit main");
}
```